# What's the difference between "remain" and "is"?

Tags: verbs

Consider that masking tape A and masking tape B are on a car, and that the car should be painted after removing masking tape A and before removing masking tape B.

I am trying to describe this process using "while".  My drafts are as follows:

1. Paint the car while masking tape A **remains removed** and while masking tape B **remains unremoved**.
2. Paint the car while masking tape A **is removed** and while masking tape B **is unremoved**.

Could you advise me on which sentence describes the process more properly?

Comment: The simplest would be to say it as you do in the first sentence of your question (using _before_ and _after_)!

Comment: I’m closing this question because based on the comments, (1) the OP doesn't actually want what the question says, and (2) they are not interested in forming a natural English sentence. So this is out of the scope of ELL SE

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Paint the car while masking tape A remains removed and while masking tape B remains unremoved.

> 2. Paint the car while masking tape A is removed and while masking tape B is unremoved.

If tape A is not going to be reinstated, *while* would not be appropriate to describe this tape.  In (1), it suggests that tape A could be reinstated.

(2) sounds unnatural.

If tape A is not going to be reinstated, we could say

> Paint the car [after masking tape A has been removed] and [while masking tape B remains unremoved/is still in place].

If tape A is going to be reinstated, we could say

> Paint the car while [masking tape A remains removed and masking tape B remains unremoved/is still in place].

We can delete the second subordinating conjunction *while*.

Answer (score 0):

"Remain" means to not go away, or to not change. So it cannot apply to tape A because it gets removed, which means, it goes away.

"While" means "at the same time as", so painting the car *while* tape A is removed means painting the car and removing the tape *at the same time*, which is not what you want to say.

Also, "paint the car ... while tape B remains" means you should paint the car, but *stop painting if tape B disappears*, which is also not what you want.

So, I can't think of any way to reword your sentence using "while" in a correct and natural way. If you're trying to make sentences with while, then choose two things that are happening at the same time, or where one action depends on the other, like "Plant the seeds in the ground while the sun is shining." Planting the seeds depends on the sun shining, but painting the car doesn't depend on the tape.

Comment: How about "in a state"? Paint the car in a state where masking tape A has been removed and where masking tape B remains without being removed.

Comment: @rama9 Which is your main goal here? Do you want someone to write the sentence naturally for you, or do you want to learn about some point of English?

Comment: You said  "painting the car doesn't depend on the tape".  But, I made the sentence to mean that the area covered with tape A needs to be painted so tape A should remain removed during painting of the car, whereas the area covered with tape B is not needed to be painted so tape B should remain unremoved during the painting.   I understand the expressions "remain removed/unremoved" may sound unnatural, but I want to use the term "remove" for some reasons.

Comment: @rama9 Then this is no longer a question about English, and is more like a word puzzle. We help people learn natural English here, and answer questions about specific aspects of the English language. This is not that. I'm closing this question is off-topic

Answer (score 0):

From a technical writing perspective, here's one way of doing it.

(at some prior point)

Apply tape A.

Apply tape B.

(your current situation)

Remove tape A.

Paint the car.

That's all you need to say. The person following the instructions will understand that anything you don't explicitly say to remove stays in place.

Anyways, so if you want to know how to handle the verbs "remain" in the context of these two tapes, the answer is that you don't use the word "remain" at all, because there's no need to use it. You can get what you want by clearly stating how to paint the car. That's not only a valid answer, it's an answer given by a guy who has faced the very same situation many many times in a professional capacity.

Comment: "remain" and "while" are not essential. I want to describe the state of those tapes during painting.  I made another draft.  Does this make sense? "Paint the car in a state where (under a condition where) masking tape A has been removed and where masking tape B remains without being removed"